# Combining a set of reversable paths

Tags: arrays, perl, set

I need some help recognizing this problem and finding a solution. I don't need someone to code the solution, just to say how to go about solving it.

An array of hashes, each hash containing one path, its ID, and its order (forward (F) or reverse (R))

Each path is initialized in the F position

```
my @paths = (
    { id => 1, path => [ A, B ],    order => 'F' },
    { id => 2, path => [ C, D, E ], order => 'F' },
    { id => 3, path => [ E, B ],    order => 'F' }
);
```

Each node or vertex of each path also has an orientation ( + or - )

```
my %plus_minus;
$plus_minus{1}{A} = '+';
$plus_minus{1}{B} = '+';
$plus_minus{2}{C} = '+';
$plus_minus{2}{D} = '-';
$plus_minus{2}{E} = '-';
$plus_minus{3}{E} = '-';
$plus_minus{3}{B} = '-';
```

You can reverse the order of a path ( e.g., [A, B] to [B, A] )
When you reverse order from F => R or R => F you also switch the orientation of each node in the path from + to - or - to +

The paths with orientations look like this:

1. A+ : B+
2. C+ : D- : E-
3. E- : B-

This is the problem input

For output, I'd like to know whether or not it is possible by reversing path orders to create a consensus path, and also what is the way to do this such that you are guaranteed to find the consensus path.

For example, if we reversed path 1 we'd get:

1. B- : A-
2. C+ : D- : E-
3. E- : B-

and the resulting consensus path would be:

C+ : D- : E- : B- : A-

But it's not clear to reverse path 1 first. For example, what if we reverse 3 first? So you can't proceed randomly.

Does anyone recognize this problem or know how to solve it?

Comment: Are the path parts say [ A, B ] unique? or can there be [ A, C ] also? Can there be loops?  If the answer is [ unique=YES, loops=NO ], you could create a hash of path parts `A+ -> B+`, `B- -> A-`, etc. and then just try out the different paths starting with each node to see which one is longest.

Comment: So a consensus path is a path that uses all the paths or their reverse?  But you can only use each path once and you can't use both a path and it's reverse?

Comment: Or is a consensus path one that uses all the nodes, but not necessarily all the available paths?  If so, can nodes be used more than once?

Comment: Just to clarify: there doesn't need to be a consensus path but there could be one. What I REALLY WANT TO KNOW IS whether it is possible to obtain an ordering of paths such that any node or vertex that appears in more than one path is either all + or all - ( it can't be + in one path and - in the other )

Comment: unique: NO loops: YES

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking for isn't easy, and I'm not exactly clear about your requirements

This partial solution takes the brute-force approach of creating a directed graph, adding all the paths from your data and their reversals, and finding the longest path in the resulting data structure

Using your sample data, it produces the ***reverse*** of the *consensus path* that you expect, but according to your rules there will always be two equally valid answers if there are any at all, and because of the random nature of Perl hashes, either one may be presented as the result from one run to the next

If I have understood you correctly then you also need to ensure that the result contains all of the paths in the original data

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

use Graph::Directed;
use List::Util 'max';
use List::MoreUtils 'first_index';

my @paths = (
    { id => 1, path => [ qw[ A B ] ],   order => 'F' },
    { id => 2, path => [ qw[ C D E ] ], order => 'F' },
    { id => 3, path => [ qw[ E B ] ],   order => 'F' },
);

my %plus_minus;
$plus_minus{1}{A} = '+';
$plus_minus{1}{B} = '+';
$plus_minus{2}{C} = '+';
$plus_minus{2}{D} = '-';
$plus_minus{2}{E} = '-';
$plus_minus{3}{E} = '-';
$plus_minus{3}{B} = '-';

# index the array by ID
#
my %paths;
$paths{$_->{id}} = $_ for @paths;

# Incorporate the inexplicably separate plus-minus data
#
for my $id ( keys %plus_minus ) {

    my $nodes = $plus_minus{$id};

    for my $node ( keys %$nodes ) {

        my $sign  = $nodes->{$node};
        my $nodes = $paths{$id}{path};

        my $i = first_index { $_ eq $node } @$nodes;
        die sprintf "Node $node not found in path ID $id" if $i < 0;

        $nodes->[$i] .= $sign;
    }
}

# Add the reverse paths to the hash:
#     - Change the `order` field to `R` (original is reliably `F`)
#     - Reverse the order of the elements of `path`
#     - Reverse the sign of the elements of `path`
#
my $n = max map { $_->{id} } values %paths;

for my $path ( @paths ) {

    my $nodes = $path->{path};
    my $new_id = ++$n;

    $paths{$new_id} = {
        id    => $new_id,
        order => 'R',
        path  => [
            map {
                s/([+-])/ $1 eq '+' ? '-' : '+' /er or die;
            } reverse @$nodes
        ],
    };
}

# Build the directed graph
#
my $g = Graph::Directed->new;

for my $path ( values %paths ) {
    my $nodes = $path->{path};

    for my $i ( 0 .. $#$nodes - 1 ) {
        $g->add_edge(@{$nodes}[$i, $i+1]);
    }
}

# Report the longest path
#
say join ' : ', $g->longest_path;
```

#### output

```
C+ : D- : E- : B- : A-
```

Comment: Sorry I misspoke when I posed the question: there doesn't have to be a consensus path. All I'm looking for is an ordering of paths such that any node is all + or all - among the paths. Some nodes will only be in one path; those in two or more could be --, +-, -+ or ++. Burt if such an ordering is possible, and it doesn't have to be, I'd like to know how to find it. thanks